# foreach loop with a condition

Tags: c#, foreach

Is there a way to do the following in one statement?

```
foreach(CheckBox subset in groupBox_subset.Controls)
    if(subset.Checked) { ... }
```

Comment: Just funny these simple questions with 6+ answers in 1 second

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure:

```
foreach (CheckBox subset in groupBox_subset.Controls
                                           .Cast<CheckBox>()
                                           .Where(c => c.Checked))
{
   ...
}
```

The [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) call is required because the `Controls` property only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`, but LINQ basically works on strongly-typed collections. In other words, your existing code is *actually* closer to:

```
foreach(Object tmp in groupBox_subset.Controls)
{
    CheckBox subset = (CheckBox) tmp;
    if(subset.Checked) { ... }
}
```

If you want to be able to ignore non-`CheckBox` controls, you want the [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method instead of `Cast` in the top snippet:

```
foreach (CheckBox subset in groupBox_subset.Controls
                                           .OfType<CheckBox>()
                                           .Where(c => c.Checked))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is:

```
foreach(CheckBox subset in groupBox_subset.Controls.Cast<CheckBox>()
                                                   .Where(x => x.Checked))
```

However, this only works if all items in `Controls` are of type `CheckBox`. If there is at least one item in `Controls` that is not a `CheckBox`, this will throw an exception. But so does your code.

Comment: So we just handle the exception? Or is there a cleaner alternative?

Comment: @Shankar: See my answer for an alternative. It depends on what you want - sometimes you actually *want* the exception, as it shows that something isn't as you expect it to be.

Comment: If you are **sure** that there will be only `CheckBox`es in that `Controls` collection, no handling is required. If the exception will occur, you know something is wrong. The original code indicates that he is sure. However, if you are not sure, `OfType<T>` would be a better alternative to `Cast<T>` as first shown by Darin und subsequently explained by Jon.

Answer (score 7):

You could use LINQ to select the elements matching this requirement:

```
var controls = groupBox_subset.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked);
```

Answer (score 3):

You know, you're always one (or more) level of abstraction away from the desired syntax that expresses your intent:

```
foreach(CheckBox checkedBox in groupBox_subset.CheckedBoxes()) { ... }
```

Where the `CheckedBoxes` extension method can be implemented by looking at the other answers.